# What does the circle mean in this picture?

Tags: organic-chemistry

So I found this picture on wikipedia and I was wondering what this big circle (which all of the substituents were attached to) meant.

[image]

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apamin

Comment: Well, that's a ring. It would be pretty hard to draw such polypeptide with accurate geometry, making it still readable.

Comment: BTW you should link directly to where you found it.

Comment: External addresses and links may change and become defunct.  In case of an illustration like the one from wikipedia, just provide the illustration itself including a proper note of the source of origin.

Comment: You might be interested: Cyclic polymer https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mechanism-of-formation-of-cyclic-polymer-with-controlled-molecular-weight_fig9_256830670

Answer (score 1):

Departing from amino acids, peptides are formed by the reaction of an amine and a carboxylic acid via an amide bond.  This may yield linear peptides, or [cyclic peptides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_peptide), and apamin is only one example of them.

*Sketchers* often attempt a representation which is easy to read on expense on a depiction identical to the 3D structure of a molecule; which differs from the purpose of a *structure viewer*.  To illustrate this, below is the 3D structure of the entry on [ChemSpider](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.23975893.html) the Wikipedia page you quote cross links.  For an increased clarity of the representation, I removed all hydrogen atoms from the model.

[image]

simplified model based on [ChemSpider entry 23975893](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.23975893.html)